# Asana API returning incorrect data

Tags: api, asana

The data I get from Asana API somehow is returning incorrect data.

For example, the order of the tasks return does not correspond to the current web UI..which is necessary for me to go through the items and take tasks under a certain heading.

In addition, when I get tasks from a user, the assignee_status is incorrect as well. I have a completed task out of today but the assignee_status is still today. Is this the correct  behavior?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

(I work at Asana)

It's important to note that priority (order), assignee status, and completion are three totally separate and independently modifiable properties of a task. The Asana web UI synthesizes a view of these tasks, first presenting you the completed tasks, then the remainder of the tasks in priority order. If it is an assignee view, the tasks will be split into `today`, `upcoming`, and `later`, with all `today` tasks coming first, ordered themselves by priority, then all `upcoming`, then all `later`.

In the API, the tasks are presented in priority order regardless of completion or assignee status. If you'd like to filter the view or present it in the same way as the Asana UI, you may need to do similar groupings. You have all the information you need: the completion and assignee status comes from the task data, and the relative priorities can be determined by the relative order in which the tasks were returned.

If this doesn't resolve your question, can you elaborate on the order of tasks you expect and what you're receiving?

Comment: Hi, does that mean if I filter away the completed tasks, the tasks will be order I view it in the UI?

Comment: For a project view, yes. For a user view, you would further have to split them into Today, Upcoming, and Later the way the UI does.